# How to add location search form in event manager plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to add location search form into event manager plugin which shows only locations not events by short code. I want to location search on different template.

Comment: i want to list locations when i search with specific location title or content not event list via short code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this with [location_search_form ajax=1] short code.